# Google Sheets - Find and match value with filter

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, google-query-language

I have try using query, vlookup and filter to get data from other tab sheets

I don't know how to get data with logic condition.

Here my sheets :

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sukCRlU1UuXS6IaR8xCYs8QScH4B2m60bqsrypDkzTM/edit?usp=sharing

**Step 1 :**

I have tab sheet with list of reward

[image]

**Step 2 :**

in the other tab sheet (cust_point), in column C i want to get value from tab sheet Reward where it use match and logic condition >= and <=.
Then here my **expectation** :

[image]

**Problem :**

First, i try with formula

> =QUERY(Reward!A2:B, "SELECT A WHERE B <= '"&C2&"'", 1)

then the result just showed but doesn't match

Second, i try with formula

> =FILTER(Reward!A2:B,C2>=Reward!B2:B)

Third, i try with formula

> =IF(VLOOKUP(C2,Reward!B2:B,1,FALSE), C2>=Reward!B2:B)

They all formula doesn't get value with match data like my expectation

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(10000-B2:B; 
 SORT({10000-Reward!B2:B\Reward!A2:A}); 2; 1)))
```

[image]

Comment: but i try in another G-Sheet with change ';' to ','  =ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(10000-B2:B, SORT({10000-Reward!B2:B\Reward!A2:A}), 2, 1))) got error. "Error
Formula parse error".

Comment: @dede.brahma try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(10000-B2:B, 
 SORT({10000-Reward!B2:B,Reward!A2:A}), 2, 1)))`